# A reward for editing questions to reopen them?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Is there a form of reward in editing closed questions in an effort to be re-opened?

If not, can one be introduced? I feel that a small boost to reputation points, perhaps +5 for getting a question reopened would encourage more users to at least attempt to get a question back on-topic. For example, [Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) (where I usually am) tends to get questions that, with a bit of re-wording, could be valid. But no one (seems) to bother, so they just sit in limbo until they get removed.

Comment: If anything it should be badge. Awarding rep might increase the useless edits I sometimes see. Maybe something for winter bash to try out.

Comment: Why must every good action result in a reward?  If a closed question can be improved it should be improved.  That's your job as a reviewer, if you won't do that without a reward, don't be a reviewer of closed questions

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but I've seen multiple edits done before a question was reopened and I am not sure who to reward in this case. As Ben N answered below, a badge or two would be enough, I think.

Comment: @rene Perhaps stick a minimum rep count for editing Closed questions?

Comment: @Rathony Fair point. Ben Has put a good answer.

Comment: @DanBrown No, that doesn't sound right. Anyone who thinks they can salvage a question with an edit should be able to do so. Bad editors should be caught differently.

Comment: @rene Fair enough.

Answer (score 8):

Currently, you get progress toward the edit badges and (if you're reviewing in the Reopen Votes queue) toward the review badges. I would be wary of adding a reputation bonus because it could be very easy to exploit: just look for questions with pending reopen votes - or run through the RV queue - and make some edits to each of them. We could require the edits to be made before any reopen votes are cast, but for posts with multiple editors, we'd still need a way to automatically determine which edit did the trick.

Attempting to save closed questions is a very good thing to do; we just have to be careful in how we encourage it. Maybe have a chat event dedicated to salvaging worthwhile closed questions?

For what it's worth, during Winter Bash 2015, the hat [I'm Batman](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/im-batman) was awarded for editing a question that was later reopened.

Comment: I vaguely recalled such hat but couldn't find it. Luckily your search skills were better than mine ...

Comment: Yeah, this sounds much better. Provided some incentive exists, I'm happy.